# Calculate shipping cost based on weight React

Tags: reactjs

i am doing an e-commerce with Nextjs and Strapi, everything works fine but since i am new to e-commerces i didn't know how to implement this functionality, is there any component, library, that can help to add shipping methods / calculate shipping costs?. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Post the code that you have tried to solve your problem.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.